# Cannot switch Bluetooth on and off from GUI or with function key, however it works from the terminal

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

Today I've realized that I can't switch bluetooth on and off

(i) from the settings GUI with the slider (the slider moves, yet there is no menu available for selecting detected devices) and
(ii) by pressing the respective function key on my Lenovo Thinkpad T470 running Ubuntu 18.04.

Interestingly, it has worked fine previously and I can switch bluetooth on and off from the command line with `sudo rfkill unblock all` and `rfkill block bluetooth`, respectively.

What is the problem here?

Additional info:

- `rfkill list` returns that bluetooth is soft- but not hard blocked.

Comment: Maybe the "GUI slider" doesn't use "unblock all" and "block bluetooth"? Hopefully someone who knows for sure posts an answer as this could address a lot of other questions.

Comment: Funnily enough, in my case a simple reboot solved the problem...